# KeyError with Pandas CSV

Tags: python, pandas

Getting `KeyError: Revenue`

My CSV file

```
Product,Revenue
Onetap Master,538.07
Aimware Masterpack,306.06
Personal Config,159.94
Aimware Lua,29.95
Config Swap,22.76
```

The code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(open('sales.csv'),index_col=1, sep=',')
print(df.columns.tolist())
pd.value_counts(df['Revenue']).plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

When I use `Product` instead of `Revenue` it works just fine

Comment: If you use this `df = pd.read_csv('sales.csv')` to read the csv file then it should all be fine. I think there is no need to use `open()` inside `pd.read_csv()` because it already opens it. And the main error here is that you are telling pandas to use 1st column as index. So it cannot find the column names properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply drop the

```
index_col=1
```

From your pd.read_csv() step, and it works. You can also skip the

```
open()
```

and

```
sep=','
```

parts of pd.read_csv()

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('sales.csv')
print(df.columns.tolist())  # returns ['Product', 'Revenue']
pd.value_counts(df['Revenue']).plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you use `index_col=1` you make the `Revenue` column the index and the dataframe looks like:

```
                    Product
Revenue                    
538.07        Onetap Master
306.06   Aimware Masterpack
159.94      Personal Config
29.95           Aimware Lua
22.76           Config Swap
```

So it is a single column dataframe, which can be make evident by examining `df.columns`: is is just `[Products]`)

TL/DR: in you want to use `Revenue` as a column, do not put it into the index